# setting neo4j uniqueness constraints in py2neo v3

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Using v2 py2neo I could put this in `__init__.py`

```
graph.cypher.execute("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:User) ASSERT n.username IS UNIQUE")
```

Why does v3 py2neo

```
graph.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:User) ASSERT n.username IS UNIQUE")
```

fail with this error?

> TypeError: unbound method run() must be called with Graph instance as
>   first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: How are you declaring the `graph` variable?

Comment: Wow! You spotted my typo from the error message... I forgot the brackets in graph = Graph()       How do you do that?

Comment: I think you answered my question but I can't give you credit for a comment?

Comment: haha, I will transform my comment to answer, right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the `graph` variable this way:

```
>>> graph = Graph()
```

instead of (without the brackets):

```
>>> graph = Graph
```

Also, alternatively to the `graph.run()` method you can use the [graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint()](http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Schema.create_uniqueness_constraint) method, like this:

```
>>> graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint("User", "username")
```